# Java generic method optional type

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method in Java:

```
public static <T extends C> ArrayList<<MyClass<T>> methodOne(parameter1)
```

Currently, I use this method to get an ArrayList of a specific type of MyClass as follows (A and B are subclasses of C):

```
ArrayList<MyClass<A>> result = methodOne<A>(param1);
```

or

```
ArrayList<MyClass<B>> result = methodOne<B>(param1);
```

Now I have another need and it's for an ArrayList that holds MyClass of both types:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> result = methodOne<MyClass>(param1);
```

However, I cannot return `ArrayList<MyClass>` from methodOne because it declares that it returns an `ArrayList<MyClass<T>>` Object.

I can fix this by changing methodOne to non-generic:

```
pubic static ArrayList<MyClass> methodOne(parameter1)
```

However, I feel safer when I can specify the type of MyClass when possible. And if I use the above declaration then I will not be able to do something like:

```
ArrayList<MyClass<A>> result = methodOne<A>(param1);
```

Is there any way I can keep the current generic method and be able to specify a type for MyClass when I want and be able to leave out the type in other situations (i.e.: when the method call fills the ArrayList with both types of MyClass)?

Comment: Do `A` and `B` have something in common? For example, a superclass?

Comment: Yes they do, they have an abstract super class.
However, the ArrayList that will hold MyClass of both types will hold MyClass<A> Objects and MyClass<B> Objects (not MyClass<superclass> Objects)

Comment: The code you have provided does not look like valid Java syntax to me.

Comment: Which line is unclear

Comment: @theyuv: *all of them*. Every line of code in your question is invalid Java syntax. But besides that, even when trying to interpret them somehow, it’s unclear, what that method is supposed to do. It’s impossible for the method to put anything into the list correctly it as it doesn’t know the actual element type of the list. But it seems to be responsible of creating the list, but what for?

Answer (score 1):

> However, the ArrayList that will hold MyClass of both types will hold `MyClass<A>` Objects and `MyClass<B>` Objects (not `MyClass<superclass>` Objects)

A list that holds both `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` should have the type:

```
List<MyClass<? extends C>>
```

You can then add `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<B>` elements to your list.

---

If you need your method to return a different type at different times, it must depend in some way on the parameters to the method.  So for instance, if `methodOne()` takes a `MyClass` instance as an argument, you could define a method like this (note the `<T>` declaration, making this a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)):

```
public <T> List<MyClass<T>> methodOne(MyClass<T> param, ...)
```

Then you can have `methodOne()` return lists of the same type as the object that is passed:

```
List<MyClass<A>> result1 = methodOne(instanceOfA, ...);
List<MyClass<C>> result = methodOne((MyClass<C>)instanceOfA, ...);
```

If you do not intend to pass in an instance of the desired type, you can still get away with it by passing in the `Class` of that type, like so:

```
public <T> List<MyClass<T>> methodOne(Class<T> clazz, ...)
```

And calling:

```
List<MyClass<A>> result1 = methodOne(A.class, ...);
List<MyClass<C>> result = methodOne(C.class, ...);
```

Which alternative you prefer depends on your use case.

Comment: I get that they are incompatible types. And that MyClass<A> cannot be converted to MyClass<? extends C>

Comment: @theyuv I don't understand what you're saying; you can absolutely cast a `MyClass<A>` instance to `MyClass<? extends C>`.

Comment: Thanks! this is a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this method signature:

```
<T extends C> ArrayList<MyClass<? extends T>> methodOne(int param1)
```

which will return a List of `MyClass`-objects of `C` and its subclasses.

Use it like this:

```
ArrayList<MyClass<? extends C>> resultC = methodOne(123);
resultC.add(new MyClass<A>());
resultC.add(new MyClass<B>());
```

Full example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

interface C {}
class A implements C {}
class B implements C {}
class MyClass<X> {}

public class Generic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyClass<? extends A>> resultA = methodOne(123);
        resultA.add(new MyClass<A>());

        ArrayList<MyClass<? extends B>> resultB = methodOne(123);
        resultB.add(new MyClass<B>());

        ArrayList<MyClass<? extends C>> resultC = methodOne(123);
        resultC.add(new MyClass<A>());
        resultC.add(new MyClass<B>());
    }

    static <T extends C> ArrayList<MyClass<? extends T>> methodOne(int param1) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, because even if `class A` extends `class B`, `List<A>` does not extends `List<B>`. This is because a `A` object supports all attributes and methods of `B` with same signature.

But `List<B>` has a `add` method accepting a `B` object, where `List<A>` only accepts `A` elements.

But the `addAll` method has a nice signature (for a `List<E>`) :

```
boolean     addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

So if it is acceptable, you could do :

```
ArrayList<MyClass<? extends abstractAncestor>> l = new ArrayList<MyClass<? extends abstractAncestor>>();
l.addAll(method1<MyClass<A>>(param1));
l.addAll(method1<MyClass<B>>(param1));
```

Comment: @Holger : I was not that far ;-) . Thanks for noticing the mistake !